# Angular 4, awaiting something before http call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an http service with a method like this:

```
  get(url): Promise<Object> {
    //await something here before next line
        return this.httpClient.get(url)
           .map((res) => {
                   return res as Object
                })
              .toPromise();
```

I need to call a method that eventually perform some object updates.  How do I make the above method wait until the other is finished?

Comment: call this from the `.then()` of the function that you need to wait on?

Comment: Is the other method asynchronous ? Does that need to the response of this call ?

Comment: @Skeptor, it does not need to get the result of this call, but needs to wait till that call completes.  This is the aquireToken method that gets the new token from Azure AD, in the background, and updates a bunch of storage
I don't think it should be async, but if it is, it may cause UI blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done many ways. One of them is `forkJoin` ( which is similar to `promise.all`)

```
// parallel method you want to execute , let this return an observable
doSomething(){
    return this.http.get('token'.... );
}

get(url): Promise<Object> {
   return Observable.forkJoin([doSomething(),this.httpClient.get(url)])
       .map((res) => { //res is an array with both outputs
            // we are only concerned with second response 
            return res[1] as Object; 
        })
        .toPromise();
```

Comment: will this wait for doSomething() to finish?

Comment: yes, It runs both in parallel and executes map only after both are completed

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
    get(url): Promise<Object> {
           return this.sendRequest(url, 'get', '')
                   .map((res) => {
                        return res as Object
                      })
                   .toPromise();
        }

    sendRequest(url, type, body): Observable<any> {
           return this.adalService.acquireToken()
               .flatMap((token: string) => {
//I am not using the result of the flatmap, only exploiting it to ensure resolution, httpClient is being intercepted with the updated values
                  return this.httpClient[type](url, body)
           });
    }
```